# Error en operaciones matematicas (Modelo, Vista, Controlador)

Tags: java, mvc

Tengo un problema con algunas operaciones matemáticas en mi programa, utilizo el patrón Modelo-vista-controlador, así que lo importante aquí es el modelo y el controlador. El error aparece en sumar y multiplicar.

Mi programa hace las operaciones, y el resultado de sumar es: 4x elevado a 1 / y el resultado de multiplicar es: 2x elevado a 2

Pero esos resultados son incorrectos, la respuesta correcta para sumar (sumar) debe ser 2x elevado a 1 y para multiplicar (multiplicar) debe ser 1x elevado 2. Adjunto el codigo de mi clase modelo y controlador.

```
public class Modelo
```

{

```
int valor;
int orden;

public Modelo()
{
    this.valor=0;
    this.orden=0;
}
public Modelo(int val, int ord)
{
    this.valor=val;
    this.orden=ord;
}

public String mostrarMonomio(Modelo m)
{
    String cadena = null;
    cadena = m.valor+"x elevado a "+m.orden;
    return (cadena);
}
//función sumar
public Modelo sumaMonomio(Modelo m)
{
    if(this.orden==m.orden)
    {
        return (new Modelo (this.valor+m.valor, this.orden));
    }
    else
    {
        return (null);
    }
}
//Función multiplicar
public Modelo multiplicarMonomio(Modelo m)
{
    return (new Modelo (this.valor*m.valor, this.orden+m.orden));
}
```

}
Parte de mi controlador y codigo vista

```
if(objvista.btnOperar2.equals(evento.getSource()))
    {
        objmodelo = new Modelo(Integer.parseInt(objvista.txtValorMonomio1.getText()),Integer.parseInt(objvista.txtOrdenMonomio1.getText()));
        objmodelo = new Modelo(Integer.parseInt(objvista.txtValorMonomio2.getText()),Integer.parseInt(objvista.txtOrdenMonomio2.getText()));


        if(evento.getActionCommand()=="Sumar")
        {
            objmodelo=objmodelo.sumaMonomio(objmodelo);
        }

        else if(evento.getActionCommand()=="Multiplicar")
        {
            objmodelo=objmodelo.multiplicarMonomio(objmodelo);

        }
        objvista.txtResultado2.setText(objmodelo.mostrarMonomio(objmodelo.sumaMonomio(objmodelo)));
    }   

public Controlador(Vista objVista, Modelo objModelo) 
{
    this.objvista = objVista;
    this.objmodelo = objModelo;

    objVista.mniCambiarSigno.addActionListener(this);
    objVista.mniDerivar.addActionListener(this);
    objVista.mniMultiplicar.addActionListener(this);
    objVista.mniRestar.addActionListener(this);
    objVista.mniSalir.addActionListener(this);
    objVista.mniSumar.addActionListener(this);  
    objVista.btnOperar1.addActionListener(this);
    objVista.btnOperar2.addActionListener(this);
    objVista.dlgDatos.addWindowListener(this);
    objVista.addWindowListener(this); 
}

public Vista()
{
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    setTitle("Monomios");
    setBackground(Color.blue);

    mnArchivo.add(mniSalir);
    mb.add(mnArchivo);
    mnOperar.add(mniCambiarSigno);
    mnOperar.add(mniSumar);
    mnOperar.add(mniRestar);
    mnOperar.add(mniMultiplicar);
    mnOperar.add(mniDerivar);
    mb.add(mnOperar);

    setMenuBar(mb);
    pnlUnMonomio.add(lblEtiqueta1);
    pnlUnMonomio.add(txtValorMonomio);
    pnlUnMonomio.add(lblEtiqueta2);
    pnlUnMonomio.add(txtOrdenMonomio);
    pnlUnMonomio.add(btnOperar1);
    pnlUnMonomio.add(txtResultado);
    pnlDosMonomios.add(lblEtiqueta3);
    pnlDosMonomios.add(txtValorMonomio1);
    pnlDosMonomios.add(lblEtiqueta4);
    pnlDosMonomios.add(txtOrdenMonomio1);
    pnlDosMonomios.add(lblEtiqueta5);
    pnlDosMonomios.add(txtValorMonomio2);
    pnlDosMonomios.add(lblEtiqueta6);
    pnlDosMonomios.add(txtOrdenMonomio2);
    pnlDosMonomios.add(btnOperar2);
    pnlDosMonomios.add(txtResultado2);
    dlgDatos.setTitle("Operaciones");
    dlgDatos.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    dlgDatos.setSize(250,100);
    setSize(350, 300);
    setVisible(true);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}
```

Comment: Agrega el código de la vista o al menos los valores que está recibiendo el controlador, ya que creas dos instancias de Modelo en la misma variable, lo que es raro y podría ser la causa de que no obtengas lo que requieres, pero no se sabe hasta ver el valor que se recibe desde la vista.

Comment: Hecho, ya he añadido lo que recibe el controlador y parte del codigo vista.

Comment: Primera cosa que no entiendo: ¿tienes una clase llamada `Modelo` y otra clase llamada `Model`? ¿Por qué? Y, ¿por qué pasas objetos del tipo `Modelo` a ciertos métodos de `Model`?

Comment: Buenas, nono, es Modelo, no se porque ha salido como Model, habra sido un fallo al pegarlo el codigo, es modelo

Comment: Error solucionado, adjunto en el codigo como lo he solucionado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(objvista.btnOperar1.equals(evento.getSource()))
    {
        objmodelo = new Modelo(Integer.parseInt(objvista.txtValorMonomio.getText()),Integer.parseInt(objvista.txtOrdenMonomio.getText()));

        if(evento.getActionCommand()=="Cambiar de signo")
        {

            objmodelo=objmodelo.cambiaSignoMonomio();
        }
        else if(evento.getActionCommand()=="Derivar")
        {
            objmodelo=objmodelo.derivarMonomio();

        }
        objvista.txtResultado.setText(objmodelo.mostrarMonomio(objmodelo));
        
    }
    //FUNCION DEL BOTON OPERAR2, RELACIONADO CON LAS FUNCIONES DE SUMAR, RESTAR, MULTIPLICAR
    //LLAMAMOS AL MODELO, DONDE TENEMOS ADJUNTADO TODAS LAS FORMULAS A REALIZAR
    if(objvista.btnOperar2.equals(evento.getSource()))
    {
        objmodelo = new Modelo(Integer.parseInt(objvista.txtValorMonomio1.getText()),Integer.parseInt(objvista.txtOrdenMonomio1.getText()));


        if(evento.getActionCommand()=="Sumar")
        {
            objmodelo=objmodelo.sumaMonomio(objmodelo);
        }

        else if(evento.getActionCommand()=="Restar")
        {
            objmodelo=objmodelo.restaMonomio(objmodelo);

        }

        else if(evento.getActionCommand()=="Multiplicar")
        {
            objmodelo=objmodelo.multiplicarMonomio(objmodelo);

        }
    }   
    objvista.txtResultado2.setText(objmodelo.mostrarMonomio(objmodelo));
    
}
```